# Concurrent assignment to a non-net '_' is not permitted

Tags: verilog, vivado

I'm getting the error:

```
concurrent assignment to a non-net 'A' is not permitted
concurrent assignment to a non-net 'B' is not permitted 
Static elaboration of top level Verilog design unit(s) in library work failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
module ex1( input reg [1:0] a,
  input reg [1:0]b,
  output wire c,
  );
  assign c=(a>b)?(a=1'b1):(c=1'b0);     
endmodule 

module testbench(
    );
    reg[1:0]a=2'b11;
    reg [1:0]b=2'b00;
    wire c;
    always#10
    begin
      a=a-2'b01;
      b=b-2'b01;
    end
    initial
      #150 $finish;
    ex1 testbench2 (.a(a),
      .b(b),.c(c));
endmodule
```

Comment: Drop the "reg" from the input. Also in your assign statement use "==" in the RHS. I am assuming you wish to do a comparison in the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 3 syntax errors in your `ex1` module.

The trailing comma in a port list is illegal.  Change:

```
output wire c,
```

to:

```
output wire c
```

It is illegal to assign a value to an input port inside a module.  This is illegal: `a=1'b1`.  Assuming it was a typo to use `a` there, and you really meant to type `c`, you should change:

```
assign c=(a>b)?(a=1'b1):(c=1'b0);
```

to:

```
assign c = (a>b) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
```

You typically never want to make an assignment inside a conditional operator like your code does.

One simulator also complains about declaring an `input` port as a `reg` type.  You should omit `reg` for `a` and `b`.  Here is the recoded module:

```
module ex1 (
    input [1:0] a,
    input [1:0] b,
    output wire c
);
    assign c = (a>b) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;     
endmodule
```